# Android SSL Download Failing

Tags: android, ssl, https, download, android-download-manager

I am trying to download a file over HTTPS using Android Download Manager which always seems to fail. I have isolated the problem to this piece of code. But I can't see the issue. Any ideas?
Android API 29

```
val uri = URL("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin")
val conn = uri.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity")
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close")
val resp = conn.responseCode
val inp = conn.inputStream
val buf = ByteArray(8192)
try {
    while (true) {
        val len = inp.read(buf)
        if (len == -1)
            break
    }
} catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
    // Log something
    // This exception always gets caught ... with some sort of SSL exception.
    throw e
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the Download Manager specifically, or are you just trying to download a file? Here's a medium article on using the Download Manager. https://medium.com/@aungkyawmyint_26195/downloading-file-properly-in-android-d8cc28d25aca

Answer (score -1):

put in your manifest file
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in a "<application"

Comment: While this might be okay in development, it's is a dangerous long-term solution per the Android docs. 

> The key reason for avoiding cleartext traffic is the lack of confidentiality, authenticity, and protections against tampering; a network attacker can eavesdrop on transmitted data and also modify it without being detected.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic